# Convert list of Objects to map of properties

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `Section` class with some attributes as below

```
class Section {
    private String name;
    private String code;
    // respective getters and setters.
}
```

Now I have a list of Section Objects and I want to convert the list to a map of name and code.
I know it can be done in a regular way as below.

```
List<Section> sections = getSections();
Map<String, String> nameCodeMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Section section : sections) {
    nameCodeMap.put(section.getCode(), section.getName());
}
```

I want to know if something similar is possible with Java-8 streams.

Comment: what if you have two same names?

Comment: I don't mind overwriting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `Section` elements that have the same getCode() value :

```
Map<String, String> map = sections.stream()
                                 .collect(toMap(Section::getCode, Section::getName);
```

If you have `Section` elements that have the same getCode() value, the previous one will raise `IllegalStateException` because it doesn't accept that.  So you have to merge them.
For example to achieve the same thing than your actual code, that is overwriting the existing value for an existing key, use this overload :

```
toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                    Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                                    BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

and return the second parameter of the merge function :

```
Map<String, String> map = sections.stream()
                                 .collect(toMap(Section::getCode, Section::getName, (a, b) -> b);
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, If the same key already exists HashMap replaces the key, it doesn't throw any `IllegalStateException `

Comment: You are right for the `HashMap`. But the collect with `toMap` has a different specification about duplicate keys.

Comment: Oh, I was under the assumption that it uses `HashMap` internally, which is not. if that's the case your 2nd answer is what I am after.

Comment: You are still right. It uses an `HashMap` under the hood. But the collector's combiner and accumulator (required to implement a collector) asserts that it contains no duplicate keys.

Answer (score 4):

Not to difficult. Just use the `toMap` collector with the appropriate method references to the getters:

```
sections.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Section::getName, Section::getCode)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find below code for the dame :

```
List<Section> sections = Arrays.asList(new Section("Pratik", "ABC"),
                                       new Section("Rohit", "XYZ"));

Map<String, String> nameCodeMap = sections.stream().collect(
                                  Collectors.toMap(section -> section.getName(),
                                                   section -> section.getCode()));

nameCodeMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key " + k + " " + "Value " + v));
```